# IOMMU GPU Passthrough

Tags: nvidia, virtualization

I hope this is the right place to ask.  My computer has an i9-10900k with the intel UHD graphics 630, or whatever.  it also has an RTX 2070S in the first PCI slot.  Can i setup a VM that will passthrough the RTX card and still use the intel gpu for main display output? all the guides I see say you need two discrete cards..

Comment: I don't see anything about needing two discrete cards for VirtualBox:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/pcipassthrough.html

Comment: I havent used that website. like, i google "how to passsthrough a gpu in a VM"

Comment: I just want to know how to set it up.  I have two monitors. do i leave both plugged into the GPU that im passing through? or Do i plug one into the motherboard for the iGPU from the intel cpu?

Comment: I don't think you will have to change your monitor configuration as the IOMMU should work with either video card.  Just follow through what that page says to follow.  As far as the Kernel part goes, I don't think I would be much help for that since my system doesn't support IOMMU.  But the next part of the `intel_iommu=on` goes into your `/etc/default/grub` file in the line of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and then will have to be added by running `sudo update-grub` for that change to take.

Comment: +1 for visual here as someone else might be aware of this to help.  =)

Comment: i tried it on my laptop, it has an igpu and gtx 1070 and it wouldnt work. my second display was plugged into the HDMI out port on it.